# How do I filter out non-int values from a double array using stream?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, int, java-stream

IntelliJ has been telling me that the Double[] is an error: bad return type in method reference: cannot convert Double[] to A[]. I have used double[], removed the ::new static reference, and still the same error. How do I resolve this error? I am attempting to get back 1.000 in the filtered results.

```
double[] pricesDoubleArr = {1.000,2.800,4.900};
double[] pricesDoubleFiltered = Arrays.stream(pricesDoubleArr)
                                      .filter(x -> x != Math.round(x))
                                      .toArray(Double[]::new);
```

Comment: This will not work in general because of small floating point inaccuracies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `.toArray();` without `Double[]::new`, because your stream hold from beginning an array of double:

```
double[] doubles = Arrays.stream(pricesDoubleArr)
        .filter(x -> x != Math.round(x))
        .toArray();
```

---

I'm not sure what are you looking from your code, but from your question:

> I am attempting to get back 1.000 in the filtered results.

I think you are looking to:

```
.filter(x -> x == (double) (int) x)
```